# Ajax post web service url error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am trying posting a data to a web service. And this service in a different project in same solution.
This project name is WebServices and web service's name is HastaTahlilUyariService.asmx. 
My code is here:

```
 $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebServices/HastaTahlilUyariService.asmx/f_HastaninAktarilacakAlislabTestleri",
                    data: "{_sTcKimlikNo:" + Cell.innerHTML + ",_iKlinikKodu:18001,_bAy:12,_iYil:2009}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(msg) {
                        alert( 'hata'+ msg);
                    }
                }
                );
```

I think my url is wrong. How can i give correct url.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you provide a fully qualified URL does the situation improve? What response are you getting on that url? A header monitor such as FireBug can be used to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: build your webservice, and configure it to run under something like `http://localhost/services/myservice.asmx` in IIS Configuration Manager. Open IIS Manager, rightclick on website -> New Virtual Directory; and navigate to the folder where your webservice is located. Name the virtual directory then `services`.

Then call the service with it's fully qualified url like `http://localhost/myservice.asmx/function`.

**The most easy way to do what you are trying to do (well, I guess)**

Create the method you want to call in your codebehind like

```
[WebMethod]
public static object MethodToCallFromAjax(string argument)
{
   //do something
   return result;
}
```

Then add a `ScriptManager` to your aspx page; and set `enablePageMethods=true`. Then call your method from JavaScript like:

```
PageMethods.MethodToCallFromAjax("argument value", function(msg) { alert(msg); });
```

*edit: removed some stuff about json and asmx that wasn't true :-)*

Comment: no, it is perfectly possible to consume asmx webservices through jquery. i do that all the time, and i'm not quite unique when it comes to that, either.

Comment: jQuery is more efficient than the built-in library that comes with asp.net. I'd suggest using it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your url to something that isn't relative to where you are right now, such as `url: '/WebServices/...` (initial slash...)

Using the firebug addon for firefox, you can inspect the AJAX callback and see what exact URL is being requested. You can copy that URL, and you should be able to point your browser to the URL of the asmx (i.e. without the last parameter, which is the method name).

Other than that, you need to make sure you've uncommented the `ScriptService` attribute in the top few lines of the asmx code file. It is commented out by default, but it needs to be there to allow jQuery to access the webservice.

Answer (score -1):

Another option to look into is the standard XMLHttpRequest object that is built into the browser (for IE 6 you have to use the ActiveX object with the same name).  It makes calling XML services pretty easy, although you end up having to some of the SOAP formatting yourself.

[Wikipedia entry for XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)